# Global integer array with No dimension

Tags: c, arrays, global

What is the concept when we define a global array with no dimension
This shows output as 16.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int arr[];

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        arr[1] = 16;

      printf("%d\n",arr[1]);
      system("PAUSE");  
      return 0;
    }
```

And even sizeof(arr) doesn't work. Why?

Comment: In GCC there is informative warning `t.c:3:9: warning: array ‘arr’ assumed to have one element [enabled by default]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`int arr[];` is a *tentative definition* there.

Clause 6.9.2, paragraph 2 says:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a *tentative definition*. **If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to `0`**.

and example 2 in paragraph 5 of that clause clarifies:

> If at the end of the translation unit containing
>
> ```
>    int i[];
> ```
>
> the array `i` still has incomplete type, the implicit initializer causes it to have one element, which is set to zero on program startup.

So *at the end of the translation unit*, your array `arr` has type `int[1]`. Before the end, its type is incomplete, hence `sizeof` doesn't work, since in `main`, the array type is still incomplete.

Accessing `arr[1]` invokes undefined behaviour, since `arr` has only one element.

Comment: +1 for showing how to answer basically any question about C implementations: *Read The [Fine] Standard!*

Answer (score 1):

GCC assumes that `arr` should only have one element. The fact that you can access other elements than `arr[0]` without segfaulting is just a coincidence. For instance, on my machine I can access `arr[1]`, `arr[10]` and `arr[100]` just fine, but `arr[1000]` causes a segfault. In general, accessing locations outside array bounds causes *undefined behavior*.