# Global array defined twice but still compiling?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

In a.h, I created an array without the `extern` keyword by mistake which should result in a tentative definition

```
a.h:

    MyStruct myArrayOfStructs [];
```

This array is then defined in a.cpp

```
a.cpp:

MyStruct myArrayOfStructs[CONSTANT];
```

This surprisingly compiled.

Why did the compiler not complain about redefinition?

Comment: Read about the difference between _definition_ and _declaration_.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242690/global-integer-array-with-no-dimension 

The empty array should constitute a tentative definition in this case.

Comment: It looks like the answers are very different for C and C++; as what language did you compile it?

Comment: I am compiling on C++. Was not aware that C vs C++ mattered in this case, do you have a source I can refer to?

Comment: VLAs are not allowed in C at file scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is illegal C++, as you expected.

3.1/2:

> A declaration is a *definition* unless it declares a function without specifying the function's body, it contains the `extern` specifier or a *linkage-specification* and neither an *initializer* nor a *function-body*, it declares a static data member in a class definition, it is a class name declaration, it is an *opaque-enum-declaration*, it is a *template-parameter*, it is a *parameter-declaration* in a function declarator that is not the *declarator* of a *function-definition*, or it is a `typedef` declaration, an *alias-declaration*, a *using-declaration*, a *static-assert-declaration*, an *attribute-declaration*, an *empty-declaration*, a *using-directive*, an explicit instantiation declaration, or an explicit specialization whose *declaration* is not a definition.

None of those exceptions apply, so the line in the header file is a definition.

3.1/5:

> A program is ill-formed if the definition of any object gives the object an incomplete type.

Perhaps your compiler is providing the "tentative declaration" behavior from C as an extension.

clang++ [says](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74209f728ef74b86) "error: definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer"

Comment: You are correct this is illegal C++, but is legal C as Lars pointed out; tested on codepad.

Answer (score 6):

That is perfectly valid.  The first (`.h`) says there exists an array somewhere, but does not instantiate it.

The second allocates it.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case because I did not specify extern in the .h file. This should constitute a definition

Edit: Googled around a bit and found this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242690/global-integer-array-with-no-dimension

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to reference a tentative definition with a tentative definition, in which case the previous tentative definition is treated as if it would be extern. The fact that one is a complete and the other one an incomplete type is not really of concern in this case.

```
int i;
int i;
```

is legal code.

```
int i = 5;
int i = 6;
```

is not legal code, because the first is not a tentative definition any longer.