# Array declaration at file scope versus function scope

Tags: c, arrays

From my high school, I have learned

1. Whenever we declare a variable then space will not be reserved for the variable.
2. Whenever we declare a variable then compiler will not look for other details such as definition of the variable.

The same implies with all data types except array as it is static in nature and size has to be specified in the beginning. But I am facing two scenarios with error in one and no error in other.

When i declare a **array** outside main() without the size the code runs smoothly but as I change it and place it inside main I get error that size must be defined.

In both case I am declaring array that is not used anywhere. Is there any difference in declaring a variable inside main() or outside it? i am bit confused and use of it eludes me.

**code sample when declared *outside* main**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a, b, c, d, e;
int bal[];

int main(void) {
    printf("successful");
    return 0;
}
```

error: None

---

**code sample when declared *inside* main**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a, b, c, d, e;
int main(void) {
    int bal[];
    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:5:5: error: array size missing in 'bal'
```

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wall`. The warning you should get is *"warning: tentative array definition assumed to have one element"*. So basically the compiler thinks that you're forward declaring the array. In other words, the compiler expects that the definition of the array (including the size) will appear later in the file.

Comment: Go to this thread..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242690/global-integer-array-with-no-dimension